# Windows AIK add Dedsktop zip file

Tags: windows, iso

Trying to build an win7 AIK. I have created an iso that will install start to finish however I need a .Zip fill added to the default user desktop.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site. What's your question?

Comment: I am having trouble getting a .zip file to automatically load on default desktop. do I need to use the answer file for this?